# X standard deviation away using MATLAB (code and data provided)

Tags: matlab, standard-deviation

i have a small problem. i have plotted standard deviation using matlab for a very large matrix. the matrix contains: 24x45x65 --->> hours x days x customers
i plotted the standard deviation and standard error. But it only shows me 1 standard devation away..what if i want to see 3 or 6 standard deviation away..is it possible to tweak the code to get it ??

code:

```
xwkd = x_weekday;
for k2 = 1:size(xwkd,1)
    hrmx = xwkd(k2,:,1:64);            % All data for hour ‘k1’
   hrmn(k2) = trimmean(hrmx(:),0.05);       % Mean
    hrsd(k2) = std(hrmx(:));        % Standard deviation
end
N = numel(hrmx);
figure(2)                           % Plot Mean ± Standard Deviation
errorbar([1:24], hrmn, hrsd)
hold on
grid
xlabel('Hour')
ylabel('kWh ± SD') 
figure(3)                           % Plot Mean ± Standard Error
errorbar([1:24], hrmn, hrsd/sqrt(N))
hold on
grid
xlabel('Hour')
ylabel('kWh ± SE')
```

the data: [x_weekday.mat](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/11719/x_weekday.mat)

thank you guys alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the error bar extents with the 3rd and 4th arguments to the [`errorbar`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html) function. So instead of just giving the standard deviation you can set the limits specifically for example:

```
nSD=3; % number of standard deviations to show
errorbar(X,Y,Y-nSD*SD,Y+nSD*SD);
```

Or as used in the OP's question the 3rd input can be used alone to set the standard deviation, in which case *the function uses `[Y-SD,Y+SD]` as the error bar extents*,

So the above is actually the same as just telling the function the standard deviation is increased by a factor of `nSD` so a silmpler alternative would be to use:

```
errorbar(X,Y,nSD*SD)
```